# concatenate tokens into single token

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to concatenate multiple tokens into a single one after other filters are applied (e.g. stopword removal).

The closest thing I can find is the [fingerprint filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-fingerprint-tokenfilter.html). Unfortunately tokens are sorted and deduplicated and I don't see a way to disable that.

I also found an [outdated plugin](https://github.com/francesconero/elasticsearch-concatenate-token-filter) which would do exactly what I want. But well,.. its outdated and doesn't work with es 7.X (2.X seems to be the last supported version).

The number of tokens is not fixed so a shingle filter with min_shingle_size=max_shingle_size doesn't work either.

Is there any other way I am missing?

---

Example:

```
In: "Hauptstraße ABC ABC"
Filter (this works so far): haupt, str, abc, abc
fingerprint*: abc_haupt_str
What I really want: hautp_str_abc_abc
```

*Intermediate solution (not exactly what I want)

Comment: Can you please share some example so that we can build the custom-analyzer if possible for you.

Comment: I added an example. Further more I found a [fork](https://github.com/tripadvisor/elasticsearch-concatenate-token-filter/tree/7.2.1) of the outdated plugin for 7.2 which gives me hope that I can modify it to work with 7.6 even though im not familiar with java.